Disc deceleration with flexible shaft
If a disc with a large inertia is being driven at a constant speed via a flexible shaft, and a constant brake torque is applied to the end of the shaft (away from the disc), will the disc deceleration still be equal to torque/inertia or is it more complicated? (ignoring other effects such as bearing friction, windage etc).
Is there a way to calculate the deceleration or would it need a dynamics software package?
None of my text books appear to cover this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to model the shaft as a flexible component, whose indefinite equation of equilibrium reads $$I \theta_{tt} - GJ \theta_{xx} = m$$. Your question looks a lot like a homework question, for the std of this forum. I've already got lots of downvotes answering this kind of question. If you recast it in a more general way, you get a detailed answer from me

Depends on the flexibility and the time you're interested in.
At the moment the brake is applied, only a small torque is transmitted to the disc because of the flexibility of the shaft.   So you get a transient period where the torque at the disk is low and the deceleration is low.
But (assuming the shaft does not fail), it is acting like a spring and eventually deforms sufficiently that the full applied torque acts on the disc.  Over the transient period the torque increases until the torque on the disc and the torque applied by the brake are equal.
So if the transient period is short enough (higher RPM, greater rigidity), then you might be able to ignore that time and just model the steady-state period as if the shaft were rigid.
